# Button Click on Android Kit Kat only activates after many clicks in phonegap build app

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I have recently built a phonegap app that has a menu that slides into view from the left and closes when you click a link on the actual menu.

I am using the jquery plugin fastclick to remove 300ms delay on touch devices. Below is the code that slides a menu in and out.

```
$('#showLeftPush').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                if ($(this).hasClass('show')) {
                    $("#cbp-spmenu-s1").animate({
                            left: "-=130"
                        }, 300, function () {
                            // Animation complete.
                            console.log('menu closed');
                        });
                    $(this).removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
                }
                else {
                    $("#cbp-spmenu-s1").animate({
                            left: "0"
                        }, 300, function () {
                            // Animation complete.
                            console.log('menu open');
                        });
                    $(this).removeClass('hide').addClass('show');
                }
                console.log('menu clicked');
            });
```

The code works fine on earlier versions of android before kit kat 4.4.1 . when i click the showLeft button, sometime the menu only opens after 10 or so click.

Is there something that i should know or am i missing something.

Please help, I have been sitting with this issue for 2 days now.

Comment: Why can't you use `touchstart` event instead of `click` ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try using Tap Event instead of click on Android Kitkat.

```
$('#showLeftPush').on("tap", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                if ($(this).hasClass('show')) {
                    $("#cbp-spmenu-s1").animate({
                            left: "-=130"
                        }, 300, function () {
                            // Animation complete.
                            console.log('menu closed');
                        });
                    $(this).removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
                }
                else {
                    $("#cbp-spmenu-s1").animate({
                            left: "0"
                        }, 300, function () {
                            // Animation complete.
                            console.log('menu open');
                        });
                    $(this).removeClass('hide').addClass('show');
                }
                console.log('menu clicked');
            });
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the simple [Panel widget](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/panel/) in jQuery mobile? giving a sample below

```
<div data-role="panel" id="mypanel" data-theme="b">
            <h3 align="center">Menu</h3>
            <ul id="list" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">           

                    <li><a href="driving_style.html" target="testframe" onclick=" header('Driving style')" data-rel="close">Driving style</a></li>
                    <li><a href="history.html" target="testframe" onclick=" header('History')" data-rel="close">History</a></li>
                    <li><a href="policy.html" target="testframe" onclick=" header('Policy')" data-rel="close">Policy</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact_us.html" target="testframe" onclick=" header('Contact us')" data-rel="close">Contact us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="settings.html" target="testframe" onclick=" header('Settings')" data-rel="close">Settings</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
```